# Как написать код, для выполнения задачи "прыжок"

Tags: python

Как написать код для выполнения зпдачи "прыжок"? На Python

Comment: Добрый день, на stackOverflow не принято задавать вопросы в формате "решите мне это". Вам необходимо добавить код, который вы уже написали и объяснить что не получается.
Подробнее можно прочитать в обзорной статье: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Также абсолютно не понятно, что вы хотите, чтоб вам сделали, ибо "задача прыжок" это явно не какая-то базовая и известная всем штука (как например сортировка пузырьком)

Answer (score 1):

https://youtu.be/pcoTDh3Rxdg?t=9

```
while True:
    jump = input("прыжок? ")
    if jump == "да":
        print("прыг")
```